# Making a website for class, a background image is higher than what I need?

Tags: html, css, image

In my CSS, the redbar.png image is going higher than it needs to be (located in #container). It's going over my horizontal nav and shouldn't be and I'm bot entirely sure how to get it to go away.. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the website with the issue : http://cit.macc.edu/~nduncan/tut4/case2/redball.htm

Here is my HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Red Ball Pizza</title>
    <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <link href="pizza.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
     <header><img src="rblogo.png" alt="Red Ball Pizza" /></header>

     <nav class="horizontal">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

     <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Salad</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pasta</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sandwiches</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pocket Pizzas</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Fish &amp; Shrimp</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Chicken &amp; Wings</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Beverages</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Dessert</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Download Menu</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Catering Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <section id="main">
        <img src="toppings.png" alt="" />
        <p>At Red Ball Pizza, we want to satisfy every appetite. That's 
           why our menu contains a variety of different items. With 
           so many choices, everyone's favorites are available!
        </p>
        <p>
           Red Ball Pizza is NOT a franchise, a chain, or a corporation. 
           It is 100% locally owned and operated. Red Ball Pizza is 
           devoted to providing the highest quality and the best service 
           possible. Our only goal is to provide you with a great 
           pizza &#8230; EVERY TIME!
        </p>

        <div class="coupon">
           <h1>Classic Combo</h1>
           <p>16" 1-Topping Pizza
              &amp; a 2-Liter of Your Choice
              For Only $14.99
           </p>
           <p>Expires 3/14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="coupon">
           <h1>Pizza &amp; Stix</h1>
           <p>16" Specialty Pizza
              Reg. Cheese Stix &amp; a 2-Liter
              For Only $21.99
           </p>
           <p>Expires 3/14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="coupon">
           <h1>1/2 Price</h1>
           <p>Buy any 16" Specialty Pizza
              at Reg. Price &amp; Get a 2nd
              Pizza For Half Price
           </p>
           <p>Expires 3/14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="coupon">
           <h1>Pizza &amp; Wings</h1>
           <p>14" 2-Topping Pizza 
              &amp; 12 Wings
              For Only $15.99
           </p>
           <p>Expires 3/31</p>
        </div>
        <div class="coupon">
           <h1>$3.00 Off</h1>
           <p>Get $3.00 Off
              any 16" Pizza at
              Menu Price
           </p>
           <p>Expires 3/31</p>
        </div>
        <div class="coupon">
           <h1>Sub Dinner</h1>
           <p>1 Toasted Sub &amp; Chips
              &amp; 1 20oz Soda
              For Only $6.99
           </p>
           <p>Expires 3/31</p>
        </div>
     </section>

     <aside>
        <h1>Pizza Pizzazz</h1>
        <ul>
           <li>93% of Americans eat pizza at least once a month.</li>
           <li>Mozzarella was originally made from the milk of Indian 
               water buffalo in the 7th century.</li>
           <li>75 acres of cheese is eaten every day.</li>
           <li>23 pounds of cheese is eaten every year by the average 
               person.</li>
           <li>The tomato was brought back to Italy by Spaniards returning 
               from Mexico in the 16th century.</li>
           <li>The busiest night for take-out pizza orders is Halloween.</li>
            <li>The first pizzeria opened in 1830 in Naples, Italy. </li>
        </ul>
     </aside>

     <footer>
        <address>
           Red Ball Pizza &bull;
           811 Beach Drive &bull;
           Ormond Beach, FL  32175 &bull;
           (386) 555 - 7499 
        </address>
     </footer>

     </div>

     </body>

     </html>
```

And here is my CSS. Problem lies in #container.

```
    header, section, aside, footer, nav {
    display: block;

    }


    /* body styles */

    body {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }


    #container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background: white url(redbar.png) top left repeat-y;
    }

    #container header {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    }

    #container  nav.horizontal {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    }

    #container  nav.horizontal ul li{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #container  nav.horizontal ul li a{
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 30px / 25px; 
    }

    #container  nav.horizontal ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255,101,101);
    color: black;
    }

    #container nav.vertical {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 200px;
    }

    #container nav.vertical ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-indent: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #container nav.vertical ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #container nav.vertical ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    }

    #main {
    background-color: rgb(255,211,211);
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    }

    #main p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 15px;
    }

    #main img{
    float: right;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 350px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 350px;
    }

    #main div.coupon {
    border: 5px dashed black;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 150px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     background-image: url(slice.png), url(notice.png);
     background-position: center, bottom right;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-color: white;
     }

    #main div.coupon h1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(192,0,0); 
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    }

    #main div.coupon p{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    }

    aside {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    }

    aside h1 {
    color: rgb(192,0,0);
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    }

    aside ul li {
    background-color: rgb(255,135,135);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black; 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    footer {
    margin-left: 200px;
    clear: left;
     }

    footer address {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Its very difficult to help when the image is not available to us, if possible add the demo or images to a live url.  Also if you could explain things in a little greater depths, that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #container nav.horizontal {
     margin-top: -16px;
 }
```

Add this to CSS.

Comment: Then mark it as answer so your question could be marked as solved. If it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go, just because I love you. I think the problem you describe is being caused by the ul element inside of your horizontal class div. By default browsers will give uls padding/margin. All I had to do to fix this was set .horizontal ul {margin:0; padding: 0;}.

Comment: For your porpoises you actually only need the margin:0, though I would recommend in the future that you should reset both margin and padding (I do it for all elements with a simple * {margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: both of the above answers will work to fix your page but I would be wary of setting too many pixel specific margins and paddings to get your basic content to sit right, this is why you are experiencing these problems to begin with. I would recommend you try to do the same site using max/min-height/width and percentage based sizing, this way it will begin to bridge the gap between a static design and a responsive one

Answer (score 0):

you could clear the nav by adding the following

## container nav.horizontal {

...
    overflow: auto;

then you probably want to add the appropriate margin / padding such as margin-bottom: 16px to get inline with the margin on the ul.

Also, you should look into css resets.  I didn't see any here and they'll make you life easier.